# Retornar String do onPostExecute()

Tags: android, asynctask

Tenho esse codigo:
MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String user = txt_usuario.getText().toString();
            final String pssw = txt_senha.getText().toString();

            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            LoginBackground lb = new LoginBackground();
            lb.execute(user, pssw);
        }
    });
}

private void retornoLogin(String ret) {

    if (ret.equals("OK"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (ret.equals("ERRO"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login incorreto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

E este:

LoginBackground:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String p1 = params[0];
    String p2 = params[1];

    SistemaHttp sHttp = new SistemaHttp(null);
    String logado = sHttp.retornaUsuario(p1, p2);

    return logado;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String str)
{
    Log.d("TESTE","(LoginBackground) onPostexecute(" + str + ")");
}
```

A `MainActivity` esta enviando dois parametros(usuario e senha) para a classe `LoginBackground` que verifica atraves da classe `SistemaHttp` se existe um usuario cadastrado com esses dados no banco de dados. Se existir, a classe `SistemaHttp` retorna para o `doInBackground` uma String a "OK".
Então eu queria pegar essa String e repassar ela para a `MainActivity` para jogá-la no metodo `RetornoLogin()` e exibir um Toast de acordo com a resposta que veio.
Obs: esta tudo funcionando ate o `onPostExecute`, coloquei um Log() para exibir a String de retorno do `doInBackground()` e ele exibe OK normal, só não sei prosseguir daí em diante.

Comment: A *AsyncTask* é uma classe interna da *Activity*?

Comment: Me desculpe sou iniciante em java(android) como assim interna da activty?

Comment: Voce quis dizer se estão na mesma classe?

Comment: Se for isso não, tenho uma classe MainActivity(com o botão) chamando a outra classe LoginBackground(que extende AsyncTask e tem os seus respectivos metodos doInbackground, onPostExecute) que verifica se existe o usuario com a classe SistemaHttp. Não sei se é isso que me perguntou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare uma interface na classe *LoginBackground*:

```
public interface OnLoginCompletedListener{
    void onLoginCompleted(String result);
}
```

Adicione uma variável de instância:

```
private OnLoginCompletedListener onLoginCompletedListener;
```

Declare um novo método:

```
public void setOnLoginCompletedListener(OnLoginCompletedListener onLoginCompletedListener){
    this.onLoginCompletedListener = onLoginCompletedListener;
}
```

Altere o `onPostExecute()` para:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String str)
{
    if(onLoginCompletedListener != null){
       //Chama o listener passando a string
        onLoginCompletedListener.onLoginCompleted(str);
    }
}
```

Faça a *Activity* que usa *LoginBackgroud* implementar a interface `OnLoginCompletedListener`

Implemente a interface:

```
@Override
void onLoginCompleted(String result){

    //Chame o método retornoLogin()
    retornoLogin(result);

    //Ou se preferir passe para a aqui o seu código
}
```

Após criar a instância de *LoginBackgroud* use o seu método `setOnLoginCompletedListener()` para *"setar"* o *listener*:

```
-----
LoginBackground lb = new LoginBackground();
lb.setOnLoginCompletedListener(MainActivity.this);
lb.execute(user, pssw);
```

O método `onLoginCompleted()` da activity será chamado quando `onPostExecute()` for executado.

Comment: Obrigado @ramaral, tava quebrando a cabeça com isso e como não entendo quase nada de java(android) fico bem perdido sem saber o que fazer.

Comment: Esta é uma das abordagens mais utilizadas para fazer comunicação entre classes.

Comment: Já fiz a releitura do `onPostExecute` da classe `AsyncTask` e alguns testes. Acho que o meu problema é esse, a falta de uma interface. Só o `onPostExecute` não funcionaria, pois preciso verificar ao final para poder chamar a próxima activity caso o login for ok. Em outro caso, eu usava o retorno pelo `.get()`, mas dessa forma não exibia a `progressBar`. Seria essa a minha confusão com o método?

Comment: Passei um bom tempo pesquisando, e ainda continuo nessa ideia. Agora realmente não sei o que fazer, se estou certo ou errado.

Comment: @rbz Se esta resposta não é o que procura, então eu continuo a não entender qual é a sua dúvida.

Comment: @ramaral Então, eu acredito que essa é a resposta, usar uma interface. A dúvida ainda é quanto ao que disse, que eu não havia entendido o método `onPostExecute`, e eu ainda não entendi qual foi a "referência", se estou deixando algo para trás... rs